# I am trying to execute a Cucumber test but I'm getting: "java: package io.cucumber.junit does not exist"

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Here is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>SeleniumProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
           <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/test/java</include>
                </includes>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

And here is the test runner:

```
package runner; 

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions( 
        plugin = {},
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        tags = "~@ignore",
        glue = {"steps"}
)

public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

After running it, I'm getting:

```
java: package io.cucumber.junit does not exist
java: package org.junit.runner does not exist

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RunWith

java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class CucumberOptions
```

How do I solve this?

I've tried:

```
mvn clean install
```

and everything seems to work:

---

### T E S T S

Running runner.RunCucumberTest
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
? Share your Cucumber Report with your team at https://reports.cucumber.io          ?
? Activate publishing with one of the following:                                    ?
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    ?
? Environment variable:                            CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    ?
? JUnit:                                           @CucumberOptions(publish = true) ?
?                                                                                   ?
? More information at https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/environment-variables/      ?
?                                                                                   ?
? Disable this message with one of the following:                                   ?
?                                                                                   ?
? src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
? src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true      ?
?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.396 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Answer (score 0):

Consider including junit dependency to you pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, added that dependency but I still get the same issue:

`java: package io.cucumber.junit does not exist`

Also, tried using 4.13.2, and it's still the same result.

Comment: Can you confirm if you have the cucumber-junit available in your maven managed dependency as in the screenshot - https://ibb.co/QQNWG16 ? Please

Comment: The issue was the pom.xml file outsite the src folder, it works now, thank you so much for making me troubleshoot this!